# MS Access INSERT INTO statement

Tags: ms-access

I need to insert form data from my VB.NET application to a Microsoft Access database.

I am getting the error `"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"` when using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO bs1 (teacher, subject, date, period)
VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test')
```

I'll admit I'm used to the MySQL type syntax, any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: Or simply "What's the queston?"

Comment: The syntax gives an SQL error, if I try to run it directly in MS Access a messagebox comes up saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement".

Answer (score 11):

I believe `date` is a reserved word. You need to encapsulate the reserved field names in square brackets:

`INSERT INTO bs1 (teacher, subject, [date], period) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test')`

EDIT: See the following article for a complete list of reserved words in Access 2002 and greater:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

~md5sum~

Comment: +1 for noting that `date` is a reserved keyword. The user should also note the importance of using # to encapsulate the date, as pointed out by Remou above.

Answer (score 5):

In Access the delimiter for literal values inserted into date fields is `#`, for text fields is `'` or `"` and numeric field values do not have a delimiter, which suggests:

```
INSERT INTO bs1 (teacher, subject, [date], period) 
VALUES ('test', 'test', #2009-12-31#, 0)
```

Comment: Great observation in picking up the [date] field and using # to encapsulate it.

Comment: @onedaywhen, I deliberately said fields, because it is only when the field is of date type that date delimiters are needed.

Comment: @Remou: your wording could be improved: "the delimter for date fields" -- In Access Database Engine SQL, you don't need to delimit *fields*. The delimiters are required for literal values.

Comment: @onedaywhen ok, you have a point, but your edit was not correct and in the number of years I have been answering questions in forums, it was a little more likely to confuse in that I have seen people trying to use date delimiters on date type data to be added to a text type field (column).

Comment: "numeric field values do not have a delimiter" -- which is a case in favour of explicitly casting literal values e.g. consider the implicit data types of these numeric literal values: SELECT TYPENAME(1E29), TYPENAME(1E28), TYPENAME(1E0), TYPENAME(1E-1), TYPENAME(1E-28), TYPENAME(1E-29)

Answer (score 5):

In Access Database Engine SQL code, when you need to specify that a literal value is of type `DATETIME`, you can either explicitly cast the value to `DATETIME` or use `#` characters to delimit the  value.

Using an explicit cast using the `CDATE()` function:

```
INSERT INTO bs1 (teacher, subject, [date], period) 
   VALUES ('test', 'test', CDATE('2009-12-31 00:00:00'), 0);
```

Using a `DATETIME` literal value:

```
INSERT INTO bs1 (teacher, subject, [date], period) 
   VALUES ('test', 'test', #2009-12-31 00:00:00#, 0);
```

When `INSERT`ing a value into a column of type `DATETIME`, if you do not specify an explicit `DATETIME` value, the engine will implicitly attempt to coerce a value to `DATETIME`. The literal value 'test' cannot be coerced to type `DATETIME` and this would appear to be the source of your syntax error.

Note: none of the above applies to the `NULL` value. In Access Database Engine SQL there is no way to cast the `NULL` value to an explicit type e.g.

```
SELECT CDATE(NULL)
```

generates an error, "Invalid use of NULL". Therefore, to specify a `NULL` `DATETIME` literal, simply use the `NULL` keyword.

It pays to remember that the Access Database Engine has but one temporal data type, being `DATETIME` (its synonyms are `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`). Even if you don't explicitly specify a time element, the resulting value will still have a time element, albeit an implicit one. Therefore, it is best to always be explicit and always include the time element when using `DATETIME` literal values.

Comment: @mgroves: when I see a down-vote without a supporting comment then I tend to suspect matters personal rather than programming -- you can always up-vote it yourself to redress the balance ;)