# StrSQL Insert into throwing an error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to Insert some new records in to an access database.

Here is my code,

```
' OPEN ACCESS APPLICATION
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase DatabasePath

 ' OPEN INTERNAL DATABASE
    Set db = objAccess.CurrentDb


BuName = Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("T1").Value
RepName = Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("T2").Value
NumberofUniqueSheets = Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("T3").Value

For i = 1 To NumberofUniqueSheets

    CmpValue = Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("U1").Value
    ShtNamedec = Split(CmpValue, "$")(0)
    HeadRow = Split(CmpValue, "$")(1)
    AddInfo = Split(CmpValue, "$")(2)
    DateInfo = Split(CmpValue, "$")(3)
    
    ' PREPARE STATEMENT
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS [BusinessUnitparam] TEXT(255), [ReportNameparam] TEXT(255),[SheetNameparam] TEXT(255), [HeaderRowparam] INTEGER, [AdditionalInfoparam] TEXT(255), [DateRequiredinfoparam] TEXT(255);" _
               & "INSERT INTO ReportTypes ([BusinessUnit], [ReportName], [SheetName], [HeaderRow], [AdditionalInfo], [DateRequiredinfo]);"

    ' BUILD TEMP QUERYDEF
    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    ' BIND PARAMS TO VARIABLES
    qdef!BusinessUnitparam = BuName
    qdef!ReportNameparam = RepName
    qdef!SheetNameparam = ShtNamedec
    qdef!HeaderRowparam = HeadRow
    qdef!AdditionalInfoparam = AddInfo
    qdef!DateRequiredinfoparam = DateInfo

    ' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
    qdef.Execute
    
Next

    Set qdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objAccess = Nothing
```

I am facing an error in the Build Temp QueryDef Statement and the error says `

> Syntax error in Insert into Statement.

`
I added the Values into the Insert Into the statement like below

```
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [BusinessUnitparam] TEXT(255), [ReportNameparam] TEXT(255),[SheetNameparam] TEXT(255), [HeaderRowparam] INTEGER, [AdditionalInfoparam] TEXT(255), [DateRequiredinfoparam] TEXT(255);" _
               & "INSERT INTO ReportTypes ([BusinessUnit], [ReportName], [SheetName], [HeaderRow], [AdditionalInfo], [DateRequiredinfo]) VALUES (BuName, RepName, ShtNamedec, HeadRow, AddInfo, DateInfo);"
```

But it gives another on Execute Action Query statement saying too few parameters expected 12. Here is the Table structure for reference -

[image: ReportTypes]

Comment: Well, you are missing the second half of the statement. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I think you need a values statement after the insert, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783486/ms-access-insert-into-statement

Comment: @majjam feel free to write that as an answer, so we can see the question has been answered.

Comment: updated the question. Adding values to that throws up another error on the next line. Saying Too few Parameters. Expected 12.

Comment: Those parameters don't correspond to the values you're setting. Take a minute, and use the parameters you are setting as values for your insert.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I am sorry. I am a beginner to this. learning and working along. Could you please explain it in the answer section. Thanks

Comment: No. You haven't supplied sufficient information for me to be sure I can answer it right (I don't have the table structure), and you've only tried for two minutes after my last comment. Provide the table structure if you want me to answer.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I am sorry. I am trying to solve this problem for the last 4 hours. I have added the table structure to the question

Comment: All text fields should be "Short Text".

Comment: @Gustav I tried short text in the table. But didn't help. Do I need to change the query in vba accordingly?

Comment: No, it was a general advice - or your parameter declarations don't make sense. Long Text should be avoided if not strictly needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works with parameters for your data table design:

```
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [BusinessUnitparam] TEXT(255), [ReportNameparam] TEXT(255),[SheetNameparam] TEXT(255), [HeaderRowparam] INTEGER, [AdditionalInfoparam] TEXT(255), [DateRequiredinfoparam] TEXT(255);" _
           & "INSERT INTO ReportTypes ([BusinessUnit], [ReportName], [SheetName], [HeaderRow], [AdditionalInfo], [DateRequiredinfo])" _
           & "SELECT BusinessUnitparam AS Expr1, ReportNameparam AS Expr2, SheetNameparam AS Expr3, HeaderRowparam AS Expr4, AdditionalInfoparam AS Expr5, DateRequiredInfoparam as Expr6;"
```

Comment: It says syntax error missing operator in query expression on the select part. It happens on ' BUILD TEMP QUERYDEF ' line

Comment: I think you may have added an extra semicolon after the INSERT INTO line. I've updated my answer with a more complete example.

Comment: Finally ! Thanks a lot. I spent a day on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is bad.

This:

```
INSERT INTO ReportTypes ([BusinessUnit], 
                         [ReportName], 
                         [SheetName], 
                         [HeaderRow], 
                         [AdditionalInfo], 
                         [DateRequiredinfo]) 
VALUES (BuName, 
        RepName,  
        ShtNamedec,  
        HeadRow,  
        AddInfo,  
        DateInfo)
```

Will not work.

Although this might:

```
"INSERT INTO ReportTypes ([BusinessUnit], 
                         [ReportName], 
                         [SheetName], 
                         [HeaderRow], 
                         [AdditionalInfo], 
                         [DateRequiredinfo]) 
VALUES ('" + BuName + "', 
        '" + RepName + "',  
        '" + ShtNamedec + "',  
        " + HeadRow + ",
        '" + AddInfo + "',  
        '" + DateInfo + "')"
```

You can probably eliminate all that parameters assignment stuff.  I don't see it adding value here.

Comment: But I am not feeding the values from a table. I am feeding it from a variable. That's where I am struck.

Comment: modified.  btw if you want to pass numbers in then eliminate the single quotes.  like if HeadRow is to be handled as an integer, is should be `" + HeadRow + "` instead of `'" + HeadRow + "'`.

Comment: I see that it's an integer, I went ahead and removed the single quotes.

Comment: It says Syntax error on the code tried both the cases of HeadRow as well !